# Что за ошибка Pyinstaller и как её решить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Пытаюсь собрать прогу в .exe через Pyinstaller, но вылезает неизвестная мне ошибка:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\olegp\mini_library_2020\env\scripts\python.exe"  "C:\Users\olegp\mini_library_2020-school_pro\env\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe" -D -w -i C:\Users\olegp\mini_library_2020-school_pro\logo.ico -n "???? ?????????? 2020 Pro" LC.pyw': ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????.
```

Пример запуска pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller -D -w -i "C:\Users\olegp\Proba\logo.ico" -n "Пробный запуск" LC.pyw
```

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112761/discussion-on-question-by-dgdays----pyinstaller----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переустановите питон, пип и сам pyinstaller. В большинстве случаев подобные ошибки возникают из-за проблем, которые могут быть решены переустановкой. Да и вообще:

> Попробуйте выключить и еще раз включить (с) tproger